# how to merge lists in list (without numpy)

Tags: python

This is what i have-

```
  def merge_list(mylist)
    list1 = []
    one_len = len(mylist) 
    two_len = len(mylist[0][0])  
    for index in range(two_len):
        combine_list = []  
        for index2 in range(one_len):
            combine_list.extend([a[index] for a in mylist[
                index2]])  
        list1.append(combine_list)

    return list1
```

But i have a problem with the output-
for example:

input-

```
 mylist=[[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]]
```

in short-

```
[[[1]*3]*4, [[2]*3]*4, [[3]*3]*4]
```

the output is -

```
[[[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]]]
```

and not -

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]
```

in short-

```
[[[1, 2, 3]]*3]*4
```

I would be happy to solve the problem and advise how to shorten the code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix your code, you just need to update the `return` statement like this:

```
return [list1]
```

Though there is still a hidden problem when your inner lists lengths are longer than one element. Check your outputs with sample inputs like `[[[2,1], [3,1]]]`.

One further - more compact - solution may be obtained by concatenating the inner lists within a cycle, then recreate the number of dimensions you need, moving the complexity from O(n^2) to O(n).

```
mylist = [[[2,1]],[[3,1]]]

def merge_list(mylist):
    l_out = []
    for l in mylist:
        l_out += l[0]

    return [[l_out]]
```

---

**EDIT**: In case of more complex inputs, you can extract first all elements and eventually fix the dimensions. This will still bring O(n^2) complexity though:

```
def merge_list(lst):
    elements = [[] for _ in range(len(mylist[0]))]
    for l1 in mylist:
        for idx, l2 in enumerate(l1):
            elements[idx] += l2

    return [elements]

merge_list(mylist)
```

Input:

```
[[[1], [1]], [[2], [2]], [[3], [3]]]
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Comment: I updated my question, the function you offered returns-[[[1, 2, 3]]] insted-[[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]]].

Comment: Does this solution work for you? @yaeB

Comment: No, it returns-[[[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]]] insted-[[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]]].

Comment: Oh okay, I think I got what you meant, try now. @yaeB

Comment: I have an index error-IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: forgot to update the declaration of `elements`

Comment: I realy appriciate your help.                                                      
 This solution  does not work well it returns- [[[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]]] insted-[[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]]].

Comment: You're right, the declaration now should be generalized @yaeB

Comment: What do i need to add if i want that the function will work on a bigger lists, for example if the input-[[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]], [[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]], [[3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3]]]                            
and the wanted output-                        
 [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]      
 with the current function(you suggested) the output is- 
                                                                                     
 [[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]]]

Comment: Your first output (the one in the example) is produced by a different algorithm than the example in your last comment. If you should apply the last comment algorithm to the first example, you would end up with `(Input: [[[1], [1]], [[2], [2]], [[3], [3]]], Output: [[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]]])` instead of `Output: [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]`, right?

Comment: I can't figure out what the difference is between the requested output and the actual output you specified in the previous comment.

Comment: In general I am looking for an algorithm that works on any dimension of a list, the example I gave in the body of the question was for illustration but I need the algorithm to work on both ,the example I wrote in the comment and the example in the body of the question and on larger lists too.